# Executing JS before whole DOM is ready

Tags: javascript, dom, ready

Ok, I made 2 posts about this but somehow I can't get it into my little mind.

So I concluded that if we have something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
func1();
</script>
```

and func1() is defined in somefile.js, it is guaranteed to run when browser reaches that inline .

However, what if I have a big page (not taking into account images etc, just html) that takes a few seconds to load and for DOM to become ready (as I understand the DOM becomes ready when the whole html code has been loaded and parsed) and I want some code to be executed and work on parts of the page that have been loaded while the rest of the big page is still loading?

For example something like:

```
<div id="div1">Some div where content will be inserted by the inline javascript below</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> notifyPartLoaded("div1"); </script>
```

^^ Does something like this exist?

Comment: Is `func1` defined in `somefile.js` or inline?

Comment: oops, just noticed the mistake. func1() is defined in somefile.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain what your question is, but a simple way to ensure DOM ready is to place your JavaScript at the bottom of the HTML, just in side the closing `</body>` tag.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>some title</title>
        <!-- this script could go toward the bottom too, but it must be before --> 
        <!--   your script if your script relies on it -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="somefile.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div id="div1">Some div where content will be inserted by the inline javascript below</div>
        <!-- your HTML -->
        <!-- your HTML -->
        <!-- your HTML -->

        <!-- Place your script last -->
        <!-- ...though it would be better to have it in a separate file -->
        <script type="text/javascript"> notifyPartLoaded("div1"); </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Because your code is after all the other elements, they will exist for manipulation when your code finally loads and runs.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid waiting until the whole DOM is ready which would take a long time on a huge page. However it seems in a case where an element #div1 followed by an inline script, is not guaranteed to be available to that <script> to manipulate right after the browser has reached the <script>. It seems the only guaranteed way is to wait until DOM has loaded completely with $(document).ready() and the such

Comment: @John: So you were wondering if you could mix scripts in with your HTML content? If so, yes, you can, but it can be a maintenance nightmare, and depending on your code, can have unexpected side effects.

Comment: ...regarding your updated comment, no, generally as long as the script comes *after* the closing of the element it manipulates, that element should be available. In other words, the code in your question should work, as long as the `notifyPartLoaded()` function had been previously loaded.

Comment: @patrick So as long as the opening <script> tag is after the closing tag of the element to be manipulated it is safe to assume that no racing condition will occur on any browser that will cause that script to not be able to see that element?

Comment: @John: With respect to relatively modern browsers (certainly IE6 and up), I believe that to be the case. I think the old, old browsers loaded the entire page, but those are long gone. Have you come across an issue where this doesn't seem to be the case?

Comment: @patrick, no I didn't it is just everyone says to use $(document).ready() etc. "to be safe" but can't answer with certainty why it is not safe to do what i did in my example above. There are cases where using document.ready() slows down the page considerably when loading a big page or server is on heavy load.

Comment: @John: Yeah, jQuery's `.ready()` is just another way to do it, but it's not the only approach. I think mixing scripts amongst your HTML markup would be high maintenance, but I could see where it could be an appropriate solution to a problem. If you do like you seem to be doing, and place the main code in functions that are invoked by your embedded scripts, it wouldn't be so bad.

Comment: Well, if your page is so huge that it takes a while to load, perhaps its a sign that you should split the content into chunks, and load them step by step...e.g you should have "load more" at the bottom of the page.